# American-Bermudan-Asian option fixed strike using finite differences

Tags: american-options, finite-difference-method, asian-option

I'm trying to price the same American-Bermudan-Asian option described in [Longstaff Schwartz (2001)](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~hjfurrer/teaching/LongstaffSchwartzAmericanOptionsLeastSquareMonteCarlo.pdf). Specifically, using finite difference methods with an explicit scheme to solve

$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac 12\sigma^2 S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + rS\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{S - A}{\tau + t}\frac{\partial V}{\partial A} &= rV, 
&(t,S,A)\in \overline\Omega,\\
V(T, S, A) &= (A - K)^+, & (S,A)\in\overline\Omega_S\times\overline\Omega_A,\\
V(t, 0, A) &= e^{-r(T-t)}\left(\frac{\tau + t}{\tau + T}A - K\right)^+, &(t, A)\in\overline\Omega_T\times\overline\Omega_A\\
\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}(t, \overline S, A) &= \frac{T-t}{\tau + T}e^{-r(T-t)}, &(t, A)\in\overline\Omega_T\times\overline\Omega_A\\
V(t, S, \overline A) &= e^{-r(T-t)}\left(\frac t\tau K + \frac{T-t}{\tau + T}S\right), &(t, S)\in\overline\Omega_T\times\overline\Omega_S\\
\end{aligned}$

where $\overline\Omega = \overline\Omega_T\times \overline\Omega_S\times\overline\Omega_A \triangleq [0,T[\times]0, \overline S[\times]0, \overline A[$ with $\overline S\gg S_0$ and $\overline A = \left(1 + \frac T\tau\right)K$. These boundary conditions have been constructed following [Kemna Vorst (1990)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0378426690900395). In particular, $\overline A$ has been chosen such that the exercise is sure for any $t$ once $A$ reaches that value (recall the running sum is not decreasing).

In particular, for a lookback period of $\tau = 1/4$, a maturity of $T=2$, and a strike price of $K=100$, the exercise at the beginning is sure only for $\overline A = 900$!

Since often, one wants to solve this problem close to the ATM (i.e. $A_0 = 100$), this grid seems to be too big. In particular, it leads to numerically unstabilities when pricing OTM (eg. $(S,A) = (80,90)$).

Is there any way/trick to simplify this boundary problem besides increasing the number of steps in the $A$ direction?